# Count from selection and access both tables with joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I stumbled upon a query that I have never done until now.

Before asking the question I looked for if another user had had the same need as me but nothing.

My goal is very simple:

having two tables:

`collaboratori` (collaborators)

`invite` (invitations)

I have to count how many invitations the collaborators have made.

table structure of collaboratori:

```
ID_Collaboratori |   cod_manager

    37                   4675
    150                  6675
    3                    6575
```

table structure of inviti:

```
invite_id |   invite_code_manager

    37              6675
    39              6575
    40              4675
    41              6675
```

if I execute the join obviously I access the two tables in this way:

```
$q_stats_prod_manager = $connessione->prepare("
SELECT * FROM  invite 
LEFT JOIN  collaboratori
ON collaboratori.cod_manager = invite.invite_code_manager  ");
$q_stats_prod_manager->execute();
$r_stats_prod_manager = $q_stats_prod_manager->get_result();
```

my need lies in showing in a table:

show me for each manager who has his cod_manager inside the `inviti` table, the number of times he sent them.

```
Name Surname Manager 1 | Number of invite: 200
Name Surname Manager 2 | Number of invite: 50
Name Surname Manager 3 | Number of invite: 10
```

not limiting myself to just one counter but also being able to access other table values ​​like any join

Comment: Tip: NEVER use `SELECT *`

Comment: @Strawberry i know i don't have to use select *, to count it was just to show how i could join with a join between the two tables to the readers of the question

Answer (score 1):

I take the liberty of putting the answer that was partially written by another user, adding a detail and explanation for future users. The resolution query for this case is the same:

```
$q_stats_prod_manager = $connessione->prepare("
SELECT count(invite.invite_id) 

/*name of what you want to call the result you will see in the while*/
AS result_count, /*you can call this value whatever you want*/

/*Start | Values ​​of the tables you are interested in selecting*/
collaboratori.nome, 
collaboratori.data_registrazione, 
invite.invite_code_manager 
/*End | Values ​​of the tables you are interested in selecting*/

FROM  collaboratori
LEFT JOIN  invite 
ON invite.invite_code_manager = collaboratori.cod_manager   group by invite.invite_code_manager

 ");
$q_stats_prod_manager->execute();
$r_stats_prod_manager = $q_stats_prod_manager->get_result();

$count_invite_manager=mysqli_fetch_array($r_stats_prod_manager);
$number_of_invite_manager = $count_invite_manager[0];
```

1. Select the id of the table you want to count
2. Give a name you wish you want to name the counted result
3. Select the values ​​of the tables on which you will perform the join you want to view
4. Join the tables
5. Show the result with while

Code while:

```
<?php while($rowstatspm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_stats_prod_manager)){ ?>
<!-- this is the fancy name you associated with your query when you wrote: AS nameofwhatyouwant -->
<?php echo $rowstatspm['result_count'] ;?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want aggregation.  I assume you want all rows for `collaboratori`, so that should be the first table for the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.cod_manager, COUNT(i.invite_code_manager)
FROM collaboratori c LEFT JOIN
     invite i
     ON c.cod_manager = i.invite_code_manager
GROUP BY c.cod_manager;
```

Your question doesn't describe where the name comes from.  But those fields should be in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @user14633289 . . . This shows the count as the second column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(invite.invite_id),collaboratori.name FROM  collaboratori
LEFT JOIN  invite 
ON invite.invite_code_manager = collaboratori.cod_manager   group by invite.invite_code_manager
```